# Showing $f$ must be constant on $\mathbb{C}$ given 3 conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we know the following about a function $f(z)$.

**i**. $f(z+1)=f(z)$ and $f(z+i)=f(z)$ for all $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

**ii**. $f$ has only isolated singularities (if any) in $\mathbb{C}$

**iii**. $f$ has no singularities on the boundary $S$ of the square with corners at $0$, $1$, $i$, and $1+i$.

Show that

**A**) If $f$ has no singularities inside $S$, then $f$ must be constant on $\mathbb{C}$.

**B**) If $f$ has only one singularity inside $S$, then that singularity cannot be a pole of order $1$.

I would appreciate if anyone out there give me any hints at how to get started on this problem. Thank you

Comment: $f$ induces a meromorphic function on the torus, the torus is a compact Riemann surface. In (A) it is holomorphic and by Liouville, it is constant. For (B), it would follow that $f$ is a biholomorphic map, i.e. that torus and sphere are biholomorphically equivalent, contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) For this part, note that, if $ f $ has no singularities inside S, then $ f $ is bounded in $ \mathbb C $. But since$ f $ is an entire function, so its constant.

B) For this part, suppose, $ \gamma $ is the boundary of the unit square formed by $ 0,1,1+i,i $. Then note that, $ \int_{\gamma} f(z)=0 $, since $ f(z)=f(z+1), f(z)=f(z+i) $ but if $ f $ has a simple pole in $ S $, then the value of the integral should be $ 2\pi i a_{-1} $ where $ a_{-1} $ is the residue at the pole. So contradiction.